# Connect Amazon S3 to QlikView to pull data

Tags: amazon-s3, qlikview

I have a Hadoop job which is executed on a daily basis. This then generates a text file which is then stored on Amazon S3.

I wish to pull the same data into QlikView. Is there any way by which I can perform the task?

Answer (score 3):

QlikView doesn't have a native connector for Amazon S3, however, you could use a product that connects your S3 bucket to the machine where QlikView resides so that QlikView could pick up your file locally i.e. it could map a drive to your S3 bucket.

There are quite a few products that offer this functionality, a couple are listed below. Most are pay-for and YMMV:

- [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/)
- [TNTDrive](http://www.tntdrive.com)
- [RSSBus' Amazon S3 Connector](http://www.rssbus.com/solutions/s3/gettingstarted.aspx) (Free version for single connections available)
- [CloudBerryLab Amazon S3 Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) (Free version available)

Comment: i was using "TNTDrive" but it says "windows can't access this disc 
the disc might be corrupt. Make sure that the
disc uses a format that windows recognizes. If the disc is unformatted you need to format it before using it"

Comment: @Naresh This is product specific (to TNTDrive) and could be caused by a number of things (e.g. Network connectivity, firewalls, permissions etc.) and probably not something that could be solved here - might be worth reading the docs for TNTDrive or asking on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)